# Popover section on top without resizing table

Tags: lightning, datatable, popover

Current I have a table and want to display a popover whenever the user mouseover's a comment section in a table. What happens when the popover executes, it resizes the table to accommodate it by pushing the next  which is the menuSelection. I need a way to position the popover above the table and not resize.

[image]

*CMP*

```
<td>
    <div class="slds slds-truncate" onmouseenter="{!c.openPop}" onmouseleave="{!c.closePop}" data-record="{!item.Comment__c}">
    <lightning:formattedRichText value="{!item.Comment__c}"/>   
     </div>
</td>   

<!-- POPOVER TOOL TIP -->  
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isHoverOver}">
    <section class="slds-popover slds-popover_walkthrough slds-popover_feature slds-nubbin_left-top" role="dialog" aura:id="pop" id="pop" aria-label="Dialog Title" aria-describedby="dialog-body-id-2">        
        <div class="slds-popover__body" id="dialog-body-id-2">
            <div class="slds-media">
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <lightning:formattedRichText value="{!item.Comment__c}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>                                                  
</aura:if>
```

*Controller*

```
openPop : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.isHoverOver', true);
},

closePop : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.isHoverOver', false);
},
```

Comment: Easier would be to use popover from [`lightning:overlayLibrary`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_overlayLibrary.htm).

Comment: @Raul Does this work for lightning:formattedRichText or just lightning:input?

Comment: Yes it would work, basically we can dynamically create a lightning:formattedRichText or any other tag and attach it to popovers body.